# Inflection point of (x+1)^(2/3)(x-2)^(1/3)

Tags: calculus

I'm confusing because I thought a inflection point must satisfy $f''(x) = 0$, however, the original problem states that there is an inflection point in $f(x) = (x+1)^\dfrac{2}{3}(x-2)^\dfrac{1}{3}$

I drew its graph on ggb so I guess it's at x=2, but $f''(2)$ does not exist (or seems to be $\infty$), is this still an inflection point? So $f''(x)$ does not always have to be true for it to be an inflection point?

Comment: $x=c$ is the point of inflection, if $f''(c)$ changes its sign in the neighborhood of $c$ and is valid when the change is from $+\infty$ to $-\infty$ or vice versa. Also in case $f''(c)$ exists and $c$ is a point of inflection, it should vanish.

Comment: $f(x) = x^{1/3}$ is a simpler function with the same behavior: $f$ is not differentiable at $x=0$ but has an inflection point at $x=0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From Stewart's calculus:

> A point $P$ on a curve $y=f(x)$ is called an **inflection point** if $f$ is continuous there and the curve changes from concave upward to concave downward or from concave downward to concave upward at $P$.

If $f$ is continuous and $f''$ switches from positive to negative at a point $c$ there will be an inflection point at $P = (c,f(c))$. If **in addition** $f''$ is defined and continuous you would get $f''(c) = 0$.